# Calculated data return NaN even it is number

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I develop a car rental system. I want to calculate the total price which is rental price times days. The price is from the Car model database in MongoDB and the days are from the search date range.

I use the `react-date-range` for user to select date input.

```
const [date, setDate] = useState([
    {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      key: "selection",
    },
  ]);

// form for get date range
<div className="w-full flex gap-4 items-center  border border-main-color-alt rounded-full py-3 px-4 relative">
    <FaCalendarAlt className="text-lg main-color-alt" />
    <span onClick={() => setOpenDate(!openDate)}>
        {`${format(date[0].startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")} to 
               ${format(date[0].endDate,"MM/dd/yyyy")}`}
    </span>
    {openDate && (
        <DateRange
         className="absolute top-10 left-4 z-20"
         editableDateInputs={true}
         onChange={(item) => setDate([item.selection])}
         moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
         ranges={date}/>)}
</div>
```

Then I calculate the input date to get the total days

```js
 // calculate days
  const MILISECONDS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  function dayDifference(date1, date2) {
    const timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / MILISECONDS_PER_DAY);
    return diffDays;
  }

  const days = dayDifference(date[0].endDate, date[0].startDate);
  
// calculate total price
  const tPrice = days * data.price; 
  
// get start date
  const start = date[0].startDate;
  
// get end date
  const end = date[0].endDate;
```

The price is in the `Car` model database that store in MongoDB. Below are the `Car` model.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const CarSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    seater: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    petrol: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    transmission: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    location: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    pickUpLocation: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    dropOffLocation: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    frontPic: {
      type: String,
    },
    backPic: {
      type: String,
    },
    interiorPic: {
      type: String,
    },
    booking: {
      type: [String],
    },
    ratings: {
      type: [String],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model("Car", CarSchema);
```

I fetch data from mongoDB and then I create a `useState` to get the input data to insert into `Booking` model database. I try to console log the `input` but the price return `Nan`.

```js
  // get input for db
  const [input] = useState({
    totalDays: days,
    // totalPrice: tPrice,
    pickUpDate: start,
    dropOffDate: end,
  });
```

But when I console log the `days`, `data.price` and `tPrice` which is the calculated total price, it return the value. Below are the result when I console log

```
  console.log(input);
  console.log(days, data.price, tPrice);
```

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZAc5.png)

Was it because the type is `Number`? But when I change it to `String`, it return `undefined`.

Comment: `const tPrice = days * data.price;`

Looks like either `days` or `data.price` is returning `undefined`. console.log `days` & `data.price` and see what went wrong there.

Comment: I try console.log both. It successfully returns the value.

Comment: where are `date` & `data` coming from? Can you please edit your post to show meaningful code.

Comment: The post edited